# jQuery Preload Multiple Images then call event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire an event after loading all images.
And also, I want to append each image tag to specific `div#ID`s like:

```
image01.jpg -> <div id="load01"></div>

image02.jpg -> <div id="load02"></div>

image03.jpg -> <div id="load03"></div>
...
```

I'm stuck in the middle...

HTML

```
<div id="blinker0">Smooth Blink</div>
<div class="profile" id="blinker1"></div>
<div class="profile" id="blinker2"></div>
<div class="profile" id="blinker3"></div>
<div class="profile" id="blinker4"></div>
<div class="profile" id="blinker5"></div>
```

JS:

```
function smBlink(){
  for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    $("#blinker0,#blinker1, #blinker2, #blinker3, #blinker4, #blinker5")
   .fadeTo('normal', 0.3)
   .fadeTo('normal', 1.0);
  }
}

$('<img />')
.attr('src', 'http://placekitten.com/160/160')
.load(function(){
$('#blinker1').append( $(this) );
smBlink();
});
```

Live sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/E4erT/

I referred to this site: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.jp/2009/02/preload-images-with-jquery.html

Comment: Do you want your `.load(function()` to be called on the `.attr()`. Because I think that's what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [imagesLoaded](http://desandro.github.com/imagesloaded/) plugin and an invisible holding element to preload the images: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/E4erT/15/

```
$.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(i, j) {
    $("#invisible").append(
    $("<img />").attr("src", 
    "http://placekitten.com/" + j * (20 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)) + 
    "/" + j * 24))
});
$(function() {
    $("#invisible").imagesLoaded(function(img) {
        img.each(function(index, el) {
            $("#blinker" + (index + 1)).append(el);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi imsky. Your solution worked like a charm :-)
it was also good to know imagesLoaded plugin. 
thanks so much. Here is my final achievement by the way.
http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/GCQLk/